# How to restore oracle 11g dmp file to a fresh oracle 11g installation

Tags: oracle

How can I create a database from a dmp-file? I do not have logs and existing database with the same structure on my system. so it has to be complete with jobs, events, tables and so on.

My second question is which option I should choose when installing oracle 11g for this scenario.
     1.Create and configure a database
     2.Install database software only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new database because no import tool (imp/impdp) does it.

You need to:

1. install the database software
2. create a new empty database with DBCA or with CREATE DATABASE.

So it means option 1 in your case (because Oracle Universal Installer gives the option to create a database with DBCA after database software installation).

Many details for running import depends on the way export has been run (export full or not). In general you will need to create the non default tablespaces if they have been used on the source database.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of Oracle consisting of three parts:

1. The Oracle software installed on the server
2. The "empty" database with all the infrastructure tables
3. Your content, i.e. your schemas and tables

To import a `.dmp` file, you'll need at least 1. and 2. Therefore you have to "Create and configure a database".

You might want to look at https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-boxes for guidance of how to do that.